# If value of column in pandas above 90th percentile then 1, if in between 75th percentile and 90th percentile then 2

Tags: pandas, group-by, percentile

I have a df column with volume data. I want to categorize the volume data as 1 if the value is above the 90-th percentile of the column, 2 if it is in between 75 th percentile and 90-th percentile.

I tried the following code:

```
def fun(vol):
    if vol1['TTQDN'].groupby('group') > vol1['TTQDN'].groupby('group').quantile(.9):
        return 1
    elif vol1['TTQDN'].groupby('group').quantile(.75) < vol1['TTQDN'].groupby('group') < vol['TTQDN'].groupby('group').quantile(.9):
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
    
vol1['Ranking'] = vol1.apply(fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly this is a silly way to do it, but it should actually be pretty efficient.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)


df = pd.DataFrame({'nums':np.random.standard_normal(size=25)})

df['quantile'] = 1 + (df['nums'] < df['nums'].quantile(.75)) + (df['nums'] < df['nums'].quantile(.90))

print("75:",df['nums'].quantile(.75), "90:", df['nums'].quantile(.90))
print(df)
```

Yields:

```
75: 0.9787379841057392 90: 1.8261557324770463
        nums  quantile
0   1.764052         2
1   0.400157         3
2   0.978738         2
3   2.240893         1
4   1.867558         1
5  -0.977278         3
6   0.950088         3
7  -0.151357         3
8  -0.103219         3
9   0.410599         3
10  0.144044         3
11  1.454274         2
12  0.761038         3
13  0.121675         3
14  0.443863         3
15  0.333674         3
16  1.494079         2
17 -0.205158         3
18  0.313068         3
19 -0.854096         3
20 -2.552990         3
21  0.653619         3
22  0.864436         3
23 -0.742165         3
24  2.269755         1
```

If you wanted to use an apply, you can do:

```
def give_applyable(seventy_fifth,nintieth):
    def fn(x):
        return 1 if x >= nintieth else 2 if x >= seventy_fifth else 3
    return fn

df['apply_ver'] = df['nums'].apply(give_applyable(df['nums'].quantile(.75), df['nums'].quantile(.90)))
```

Edit: The non-apply version is a bit faster!

Comment: Why silly, it's a great answer..

Comment: The automatic type inference between bool and int is a bit silly

Comment: `apply` isn't faster...

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it was just because of the small size. I blew up the array to 5000 and the non-apply version is faster.

Comment: How to use addition method or function method as suggested alongwith groupby

Answer (score 1):

I profiled the two approaches given by @Carbon's excellent and crafty answer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

N_values = [100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000] 

def give_applyable(seventy_fifth, nintieth):
    def fn(x):
        return 1 if x >= nintieth else 2 if x >= seventy_fifth else 3

    return fn

execution_times = {'addition_ver': [], 'apply_ver': []}

for N in N_values:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'nums': np.random.standard_normal(size=N)})

    addition_time = timeit.timeit('1 + (df["nums"] < df["nums"].quantile(.75)) + (df["nums"] < df["nums"].quantile(.90))', globals=globals(), number=1000)
    apply_time = timeit.timeit('df["nums"].apply(give_applyable(df["nums"].quantile(.75), df["nums"].quantile(.90)))', globals=globals(), number=1000)

    execution_times['addition_ver'].append(addition_time)
    execution_times['apply_ver'].append(apply_time)




plt.plot(N_values, execution_times['addition_ver'], label='Addition Ver.')
plt.plot(N_values, execution_times['apply_ver'], label='Apply Ver.')
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
plt.title('Comparison of Execution Times')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is because addition and comparison operations will take advantage of the underlying blocks of `numpy.ndarray`s and are implemented efficiently.
`apply` will increase faster as there's more python code to loop over each element. Generally you always want to avoid using `apply`.

[image]